# onBackPressed not called from Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-lifecycle, android-appcompat

I know a lot of questions are posted regarding this topic, but I can't find a workable solution.

I want the onBackPressed() to be called when I press the left arrow in the tootbar.
I'm using appcompat-v7:23:1:0.
The left arrow is working everywhere in my app but here. I suspect it is linked to the fact I start my activity from a fragment.

Activity_A > starts Fragment_A (extends SupportMapFragment) > which starts Activity_B.

I want to go back on Fragment_A when the back arrow is pressed from Activity_B.
For the moment, the arrow doesn't respond to the click, onBackPressed is not called form the toolbar but it is when the hardware back button is pressed.

I've tried adding

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

and I've added this in the manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.Activity_B"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.Activity_A" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.Activity_A"
            />
    </activity>
```

(Activities names are replaced for clarification)

Comment: Do you have custom actionbar? i.e. have you used toolbar?

Comment: No, its is the default Toolbar object from android.support.v7.widget And yes the toolbar is used everywhere in the project with success

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem was related to the xml layout of my activity_B

I have a scrollView below the toolbar. That scrollView had a `android:layout_below="@id/contact_center"` whose id doesn't exists in that activity.

I know it sounds strange but having gone back and forward with the code, I'm 100% sure that this was causing the onBackPress() to not respond.

So for people having similar problems, pay attention to your xml layout, there might be an error in there causing this strange issue. Also, be very varefull with copy-pasting code from other activities ;)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your onCreateOptionMenu

```
int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        return true;
    }
```

also add this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: did you mean 'public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {'? Doesn't work...

Comment: yeah and add getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); to your onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void setUpToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Toolbar Title");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```